# Raster data QGIS and SpatiaLite?

Tags: qgis, raster, spatial-database, spatialite, rasterlite

I am a german student and study Geoinformatik.

I have the task to store Raster data in SQLite. So use the turotial from the gaia page to Create a database and store a image (TIFF) named NaturalEarth. This was no problem. In my next step I want to add this image to qgis. I try to add a rasterlayer from my sqlite database but it doesn't work. So my question is how to load the image (raster data) from my database (sqlite) to qgis?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] where you will see that there should be only one question per question.  I think you should [edit] this to focus on asking how to display and work with rasters stored on SpatiaLite using QGIS.  Asking for [a list of] tutorials as well makes this too broad.  You should probably reference http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28086/how-to-store-raster-data-in-spatialite too, in order to show your research so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

rasterlite2 brings with it the wmslite wms server that can operate on rasterlite databases. So you run wmslite on your rasterlite db and then load the WMS in QGis.

This https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/librasterlite2/wiki?name=tutorials is the index page for rasterlite2 tutorials, and in Step 5 of https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/librasterlite2/wiki?name=planetEarth they describe how to set up the WMS service:

```
$ wmslite -db earth.sqlite
```

and what URL to use to display it in WMS clients:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/wmslite?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities
```

Note that you'll (as far as i remember) have to check "ignore axis orientation" on the WMS properties page in QGis.