# Import "OsmAnd" Hillshades into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, sqlite, osmand

I'm trying to create hillshades by importing data used by OsmAnd but I can't figure out how to do so.

When adding the data as a Vector Layer, as I normally would do with sqlite data, it appears in the Layers Panel but doesn't show anything.

[OsmAnd Hillshades](http://download.osmand.net/hillshade/) are in sqlite format. [Technical help from OsmAnd states](http://osmand.net/help-online?id=TechnicalArticles#OsmAnd_Data_Structure) that *SQLite format used in OsmAnd is based on the "BigPlanet" SQLite as supported by MOBAC*.

Looking at the sqlite file format shows that the table has columns x, y, z, s and an image blob. Is there any way to specify sqlite import format for QGIS?

PS: [This conversation](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/osmand/AdA4K3i-q0M) seems relevant but I don't understand it fully.

Answer (score 1):

Hillshades are typically a kind of raster data that's why you cant add it as a vector layer (for raster data you should use add raster layer).

That being said I dont know how to add a raster layer from a sqlite database in qgis, you could check this related question [Raster data QGIS and SpatiaLite?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/171151/raster-data-qgis-and-spatialite) .

If your goal is to get some generic hillshades you could try the QuickMapServices Plugin (add the contributed pack in setting) where you will find several hillshades layer.
Alternatively you could download some DEM of your area of interest and create your own hillshade (search for question on this site for downloading and hillshading DEM)